# Why does the CRUD code get written in a controller file but not the model file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Wondering why most of the code or business logic per se are written in the controller.rb file but not the model.rb file when business logic should be handled by the model.

When someone says business logic should be taken care of by the model, does that mean that the code should be written within the model file or does it mean that the model class takes care of the business logic?

Comment: this link probably also can help you to get more understand https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/where-do-you-put-your-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confuse business logic and application logic.

Business logic is about domain area, entities and their relationships, schema and constraints, interfaces and rules.

If you want to have an action and a view to display categories and number of articles for every category -- it's about application logic.

Consider this thought: potentially you may have different applications work with the same set of models.

Comment: So is a CRUD operation application logic for the most part?

Comment: Do your customers by creates or do they buy cars?